# How to clarify existing json data using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

Below is my JSON data that generated somehow :

```
[
  {
    id: "1926d769-319b-41ec-8bba-deabbcc44992",
    start: "2014-09-02T11:00:00",
    end: "2014-09-02T12:00:00",
    title: ""ATR" Recieved by Lender - First",
    body: ""ATR" Recieved by Lender - First",
    color: "",
    editable: false,
    officeEvent: false,
    allDay: false
  },
  {
    id: "37e65cc0-a44a-460d-acc6-f8847fcdc384",
    start: "2014-08-04T12:00:00",
    end: "2014-08-04T13:00:00",
    title: "Sign Disclosures",
    body: "Sign Disclosures",
    color: "",
    editable: false,
    officeEvent: false,
    allDay: false
  }
]
```

The first item **title** and **body** contain double quote(""), So that the JSON data showing an error. Now how can i escape this quote from whole JSON data at the same time like below.

title: "\"ATR\" Recieved by Lender - First"

How can i achieve this in Asp.Net C#?

Comment: How was the JSON generated in the first place?  Did you create it, or is it from a third party?

Comment: @Brian Rogers, Yes it is from third party. I escape title and body using title.replace("\"", "\\\"") in foreach loop. But is there any shortcut way without foreach.

Comment: If it is from a third party, you should contact them and let them know they are creating invalid JSON and request they fix it.  Quotes in a JSON string must be escaped, per the spec (see [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/)).  If there's no way to do that, then you're pretty much stuck doing what you are doing now to work around it.  A standard JSON parser will give an error if the JSON is invalid, as in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Brian is correct you really need to talk to the vendor and have them fix their data / code. For the work around without using a loop though you can use strings replace method to get the clean the JOSN.

```
string cleanJson = source.toString();
string cleanJson = cleanJson.Replace("title: \"\"", "title: \"\\\"");
string cleanJson = cleanJson.Replace("body: \"\"", "title: \"\\\"");
return convertBackToJson(cleanJson);
```

If you don't want to use a loop for performance reasons this may not be a better solution. if you are looking to speed up the processes up consider trying to break up your JSON into pieces if you can isolate the bogus records clean them and append them into the final output.